# Why isn't jQuery .one triggered in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This works fine in every other browser, but doesn't work in Internet Explorer, any ideas?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('img').one('error', function() { not being run });
});
```

Comment: Internet explorer is made for headaches.

Comment: Is there an error event in IE?

Comment: well, I think there must be - because *some* of the images are changed, but not all, and not all of the time

Comment: What happens if you try binding it without `one`? As in `jQuery(document).on('error','img',function(){/*etcetera */})`

Comment: A fine question - according to the standards it should, but the error event from an img doesn't bubble...gah

Comment: Are you sure its not a caching problem? Because on IE9, seems to work just fine.

Comment: Hmm, there were other stackoverflow posts saying it doesn't work, I'll check for caching

Comment: Very odd. IIRC, it's not so long ago that the image.error event was thoroughly reliable in IE and totally unsupported in all other browsers. Hey ho!

Comment: Did you get this working? I am seeing the same issue...

Comment: I don't believe I did - I think I had to resort to onerror as an attribute (although it was a while back)